# How to create a pattern like this using Python script or Modifiers

Tags: python, blender-internal-render-engine

[image]

Is is possible to create a pattern something like this using Python scripting in Blender?

I marked 4 different patterns inside the image above. I want to create such a pattern using Python script and/or Modifiers.

Any suggestions and tricks will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you need to create a mesh or a rendering (ie volumetric) from this pattern?

Comment: I need to create a layer with some thickness (in all three dimensions: i.e. length, height and width). So, it should be a mesh object.

Comment: Can I ask what is it? A bone section or something like that?

Comment: This is actually cytoskeleton of some plant cell.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a try with just modifiers. It's not exact, but it might get you started at least. This is with just the default cube:

[image]
<sup>*click to enlarge*</sup>

The modifier stack is as follows:

[image]
<sup>*click to enlarge*</sup>

You can adjust the "openness" of the pattern by tuning the *scale* and *ratio* of the remesh and decimate modifiers. The thickness of course comes from the wireframe modifier.

You could optionally add a *solidify* modifier after the remesh if you want a little more density to the model as well. You would get something like the following:

[image]
<sup>*click to enlarge*</sup>

Here is the .blend file for your reference. (The solidify modifier from the second image is currently disabled for render and the viewport.)

[image]